# java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readFully&#40;Ljava/io/InputStream&#59;[B&#41;V

Tags: java, struts2, weblogic12c

I get the below exception in action class when I try to submit a HTML form having file :

```
java.lang.NoSuchMethodError: org.apache.commons.io.IOUtils.readFully&#40;Ljava/io/InputStream&#59;[B&#41;V
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.get(DiskFileItem.java:315)
    at org.apache.commons.fileupload.disk.DiskFileItem.getString(DiskFileItem.java:339)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.processNormalFormField(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:177)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.processUpload(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:132)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.JakartaMultiPartRequest.parse(JakartaMultiPartRequest.java:92)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.multipart.MultiPartRequestWrapper.<init>(MultiPartRequestWrapper.java:84)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.Dispatcher.wrapRequest(Dispatcher.java:838)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.PrepareOperations.wrapRequest(PrepareOperations.java:137)
    at org.apache.struts2.dispatcher.ng.filter.StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.doFilter(StrutsPrepareAndExecuteFilter.java:91)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at org.displaytag.filter.ResponseOverrideFilter.doFilter(ResponseOverrideFilter.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.FilterChainImpl.doFilter(FilterChainImpl.java:79)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3431)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3397)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.WlsSubjectHandle.run(WlsSubjectHandle.java:57)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.doSecuredExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2280)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2196)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2174)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1621)
    at weblogic.servlet.provider.ContainerSupportProviderImpl$WlsRequestExecutor.run(ContainerSupportProviderImpl.java:256)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:311)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:263)
```

I am using Struts 2 framework for back end and Weblogic 12c as application server. 
The war deployed to server contains commons-io-2.2.jar.

What is causing this issue even when the required jar - **commons-io-2.2.jar** exists in the war deployed to Web logic 12c server?
 Is there any jar in Web logic 12c server that is conflicting with commons-io-2.2.jar bundled in the application war?

**I am getting this issue after patch - 23744018 was added to Web logic 12c server.**

Comment: Are you compiling and running your code using the same `jar` dependency?

Comment: Yes. I am using ANT tool for compiling and building war

Comment: Solved. This is a oracle product defect when patch 23744018 is applied, the application using upload feature fails presenting the above error. This issue can be fixed by applying a revised patch 25029531.

Comment: I am unable to answer my question. Please enable the option to post answer.